# Taking legend outside of grouped plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am creating multiple plots based on a groupby with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

with PdfPages(r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\time_series.pdf') as pdf:
   for i, group in df.groupby('Allotment'):


       plt.figure()
       plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
       VI_plots=group.plot(x='Year', y=['NDII_Mean', 'RGR_Mean', 'SATVI_Mean', 'SWIR32_Mean', 'NDVI_Mean', 'MTVI_Mean'],title=str(i)).get_figure()
       pdf.savefig(VI_plots)  
       plt.close(VI_plots)
print "Done Processing"
```

I want to take the legend outside of the plot, which is what I am trying to do with this line:

```
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

but it doesn't actually take it out.  The code executes just like I want except for that part and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have contradictory instructions to the legend.  Telling it `loc='center left'` means you want it in the figure, while `bbox_to_anchor` is telling it to place it elsewhere. Also, your `bbox_to_anchor` location (1, 0.5) doesn't actually take the legend out of the figure, but places it at the right edge. Try using

```
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, 0.5))
```